# Gorm count elements group by day without time

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I wish to retrieve a list of UserProfile registrations per **day**. 
The domain object UserProfile stores a Date creationDate property.
I've tried

```
def results = UserProfile.executeQuery('select u.creationDate, count(u) from UserProfile as u group by u.creationDate')
println results
```

which obviously is not what I need because data is (already) stored with complete time in it.

Any resource savvy solution will fit: projections, hql, ...

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use HQL cast function:

```
def results = UserProfile.executeQuery("""
  select cast(u.creationDate as date), count(u) 
  from UserProfile as u 
  group by cast(u.creationDate as date)
""")
```

Underlying database must support ANSI cast(... as ...) syntax for this to work, which is the case for PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server and many other DBMSs

Comment: I'm getting this exception while using CAST() function in executequery:
HibernateQueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : DATE

Answer (score 0):

Break down the date to `day`, `month` and `year` then ignore the `timestamp`.

This should give you what you need.

```
def query = 
"""
select new map(day(u.creationDate) as day, 
               month(u.creationDate) as month, 
               year(u.creationDate) as year, 
               count(u) as count)
       from UserProfile as u
       group by day(u.creationDate), 
                month(u.creationDate), 
                year(u.creationDate)
"""

//If you do not worry about dates any more then this should be enough
def results = UserProfile.executeQuery( query )

//Or create date string which can be parsed later
def refinedresults = 
    results.collect { [ "$it.year-$it.month-$it.day" : it.count ] }

//Or parse it right here
def refinedresults = 
    results.collect {
        [ Date.parse( 'yyyy-MM-dd', "$it.year-$it.month-$it.day" ) : it.count ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a ["derived" property](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) mapped as a formula to extract the date part of the date-and-time.  The exact formula will differ depending what DB you're using, for MySQL you could use something like

```
Date creationDay // not sure exactly what type this needs to be, it may need
                 // to be java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date

static mapping = {
  creationDay formula: 'DATE(creation_date)'
}
```

(the formula uses DB column names rather than GORM property names).  Now you can group by `creationDay` instead of by `creationDate` and it should do what you need.

Or instead of a "date" you could use separate fields for year, month and day as suggested in the other answer, and I think those functions are valid in H2 as well as MySQL.

Comment: Dependency on dialect was the reason for me to not consider this option. You are correct. :)